# Splitting variable to dynamic multidimensional table in powershell

Tags: powershell, multidimensional-array, dynamic

I am trying to split variable in multidimensional variable. I've got error that: "Index is out of boundaries."

I was trying to make additional variable $table() and declare it on different ways but everything is feiling.

My problem is that variable $tables have to take dynamic input (can have different number of table names divided by ":" and coordinates to that table divided by ",")

I would like to have output like:

```
$tables[0][0] = "tab_eposter"
$tables[0][1] = "2"
..
$tables[1][0] = "tab_befaring"
..
$tables[1][2] = 3
```

Can anyone help me with that?

```
function Get-Txt-From-Excel {
  
  Param(

    [Parameter(Mandatory)]
    $inFile,
    [Parameter(Mandatory)]
    $outFile,
    $ranges = "info_ordre,info_adresse",
    $tables = "tab_eposter,2,2,1,3,3,2:tab_befaring,2,3",
    $sheet = "prosjekt-info",
  )

  try{

    # Internal variables
    $ranges = $ranges -split ","
    $tables = $tables -split ":"
    
    for( $i = 0; $i -le $tables.length; $i++ ) {
      $tmp_table = $tables[$i] -split ","
      $tables[$i] = $tmp_table
    }

    Write-Host $tables[0][0]
    throw
...
```

Comment: First off, you need to use `-lt` in your for loop, not `-le`. But then... why not have it create a Hashtable with the name of the table as Key and the numeric values as array in its Value ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuing from my comment, I think it would be easier if you collect the result in a Hashtable instead of a multidimensional array.

Here's how you can do that:

```
$tables = "tab_eposter,2,2,1,3,3,2:tab_befaring,2,3"

$tables = @($tables -split ":")  # use @() to force it as array
$result = @{}                    # create a Hashtable to store the results

for ( $i = 0; $i -lt $tables.Count; $i++ ) {
  $temp = $tables[$i] -split ","
  $name, $values = $temp         # split the temp array in the name (element [0]) and the numeric values
  $result[$name] = $values
}
```

You can then refer to tha tables and their values using the normal dot notation:

```
$result.tab_befaring  # --> an array with values 2 and 3
$result.tab_eposter   # an array with values 2 2 1 3 3 and 2
```